# Can you apply surface-bonding cement over stucco as an exterior finish?

Tags: concrete, stucco

Let's say you have a wood-framed wall with cement-based stucco cladding and it's in pretty good condition, with a few typical stucco cracks. If you wanted to seal the cracks, add another layer, and change the color, could you apply surface-bonding cement instead of a (much more expensive) additional layer of stucco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as an exterior (no as an interior).

The general rule is that the hardest surface must face the side that water would be attacking from.  If you reverse it, any water that penetrates cause a pressure build up when it meets the harder surface and cause the softer material to crack.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. I was surprised that the internet didn't have more info on this idea since it seems like it would represent a substantial savings of cost and effort compared to mixing up and applying new stucco.

Comment: It is surprising how little masonry info there is on the internet.  My cousin builds rock walls for a living and couldn't even answer my questions about re-pointing. The major reasons for this seems to be that masonry is dying as a crafts due to poured concrete foundations and surface and  because it's quite labour intensive and thus not the best DIY project and more efficient to hire people with specialized equipment and knowledge.  However, as my last name literally means "mason" the engineer in me was embarrassed that I couldn't fix my own foundation and thus I researched for hours.